# ipad/iphone can't open my website

Tags: iphone, ipad, iis, hostheader

I have a website setup with IIS and Hostheader, the site won't open on iPhone/iPad with "server cannot be found"

```
 for example:
 the domain I want to show: www.example.com
 the primary domain I have: www.myorigin.com
```

I configure the DNS on www.example.com to point to www.myorigin.com, then I also setup host header on myorigin.com: example.com to point to /www/root/example

example.com works on everything except iPhone/iPad. Sarfari shows "server cannot be found"

I don't know if I explain the issue correctly, but any direction pointing is much appreciated.

Comment: How long did you wait, and what's your DNS TTL?

Comment: it's been a week already. TTL?

Comment: Why don't you give us the domain name and let us take a look?

Comment: Works just fine on mine. http://cl.ly/image/1j3Q2H3B0Z2c/IMG_1230.PNG

Comment: this is the problem. It works on some, not all. One thing I am sure is after I do a network reset on the not-working iphone/ipad, the website will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62134/discussion-between-triston-and-ceejayoz).

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your network or devices, not something we can troubleshoot.